# Hot Module Replacement : [Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'onClik' of undefined"

Tags: laravel, vue.js, webpack, hot-module-replacement

- npm v6.8.0
- laravel 5.5
- laravel.mix v4.0.14
- webpack-dev-server v^3.2.1

While running on Hot Module Replacement (npm run hot) this is the message i receive in the console
*[HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...  
[WDS] Hot Module Replacement enabled.*
 **And when i've got some changes on the lead-management.js this is the message i got** 
*[WDS] App updated. Recompiling...

[WDS] App hot update...

[HMR] Checking for updates on the server...

[Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'onClik' of undefined"
(found in Root)

TypeError: Cannot read property 'onClik' of undefined

[Vue warn]: Error in nextTick: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'onClik' of undefined" (found in Root) 

TypeError: Cannot read property 'onClik' of undefined

[HMR] Updated modules:

[HMR]  - ./resources/assets/js/lead-management.js 

[HMR] App is up to date.*

then my buttons or any of the functions is not working 
***FYI onClick is a method from my component DataTable***

**resources/assets/js/lead-management.js**

```js
import Croppa from 'vue-croppa';
import { Form, HasError, AlertError, AlertSuccess } from 'vform'
import CKEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue';
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';
import datePicker from 'vue-bootstrap-datetimepicker'

import DataTable from './components/DataTable.vue';
import Fullcalendar from './components/Fullcalendar.vue';
import Button from './components/Button.vue';
import Select2 from './components/Select2.vue';
if (module.hot){
    module.hot.accept()
}

import 'pc-bootstrap4-datetimepicker/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css';
Vue.component('datatable-component', DataTable);
Vue.component('fullcalendar-component', Fullcalendar);
Vue.component('VButton', Button);
Vue.component('select2-component',Select2);
Vue.component('my-image-cropper', Croppa.component)
Vue.component(HasError.name, HasError)
Vue.component(AlertError.name, AlertError)
Vue.component(AlertSuccess.name, AlertSuccess)

mounted: function(){// mounted part 
    this.$nextTick(function () {
        /**i have this code that give me property 'onClik' of undefined while [HMR] Checking for updates on the server**/
        this.$refs.table.onClik('.show-activity', function() {})
    }
}
```

**lead-management.blade.php**

```html
<datatable-component class="responsive table table-striped table-bordered"
    ref="table">
</datatable-component>
```

i have my assets in lead-management.blade.php

```html
<link href="{{ mix('css/lead-management.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="{{ mix('js/lead-management.js') }}" ></script>
```

**webpack.mix.js**

```js
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/assets/js/lead-management', 'public/js')
 .sass('resources/assets/sass/lead-management.scss', 'public/css');
```

Comment: Try changing it to onClick. Add the c

Comment: @TJWeems -  console.log(this.$refs.table) in mounted gives me undefined after updating lead-management.js